# Pycord error "TypeError: Object of type TextIOWrapper is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to make it where it will store channels in a JSON file. I'm new to JSON. What is causing this?

I'm using Pycord.

Code:

```
def get_channels(guild):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channels = json.loads(f)

    return channels[str(guild.id)]


@bot.slash_command(name="set-report-channel", description="Set the channel.")
async def setreportchannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channel = json.dumps(f)

    channel[str(ctx.guild.id)] = int(channel.id)

    with open('channels.json','w') as f:
        json.dumps(f, channel, indent=4)

    await ctx.respond(f"Channel set to {channel}")
```

I tried dump and load.

Comment: `json.loads(f)` should be `json.load(f)`.

Comment: `channel = json.dumps(f)` should be `channel = json.load(f)`

Comment: `json.dumps(f, channel, indent=4)` should be `json.dump(channel, f, indent=4)`

Comment: Basically, you need to learn the difference between load and dump, and that you use the versions that end with `s` when you're reading/creating a string, not a file. You also have to get the order of arguments right.

Comment: Post the full traceback message showing the line that failed. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_channels(guild):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channels = json.load(f)  # Replaced with json.load

    return channels[str(guild.id)]


@bot.slash_command(name="set-report-channel", description="Set the channel.")
async def setreportchannel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel = None):
    with open('channels.json','r') as f:
        channel = json.load(f)  # Replaced json.dumps with json.load

    channel[str(ctx.guild.id)] = int(channel.id)

    with open('channels.json','w') as f:
        json.dumps(f, channel, indent=4)

    await ctx.respond(f"Channel set to {channel}")
```

You need to use `json.load()` instead of `json.dumps()` when retrieving information from a `.json` file. `json.load()` gets a dictionary version of a `json` and allows it to be accessible.

[Documentation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-loads-in-python/)

[Difference between `json.loads` and `json.load`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads/)

You will also need to replace `json.loads` with `json.load` as `json.loads` takes a string and `json.load` takes a file.